# How to surrounded TextView with 2 divider

Tags: android, layout, textview, imageview, divider

My question is **how to surround a TextView with 2 dividers in Android** like this:

-------- TEXTVIEW ------

where "--------" is a horizontal divider in an ImageView.

I tried with a LinearLayout horizontal but I had some space and my divider was too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

replace drawable with your image

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```